# CRS changes even though set in project

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am slightly confused as to why when i am working in projects the CRS changes when I add new data, e.g. add Bing maps or try to georeference an image.

The CRS is set in the project and when I am prompted I always choose the same one, expect that it seems to end up on another one!

I know that using the same CRS is very important and I am therefore very confused as to why this keeps happening. How can I stop it from changing?

Answer (score 1):

The Openlayers plugin requires EPSG:3857 to display the bing tiles in a good looking way. In higher zoom levels it is possible to change the **project** CRS to something else afterwards, but this may fail on worldwide scenes.

If you need another CRS:

1. make a screenshot of the Openlayers background with `Project -> Save as Image`
2. load it as a raster source with **layer** CRS EPSG:3857
3. remove the original Openlayers layer
4. change the **project** CRS to the one you need.

You can repeat this for different zoom levels.

The `QuickMapServices` plugin works better with different CRS, but has no bing source layer.